# How to recursively filter an array if value exists on another array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, associative-array

I have two arrays.
The first one is the structure, an associative array that containts all elements inside categories. the name of the categories are keys inside this array. The categories can have different levels of depth:
check this example:

```
$structure = [
            'fruits'    => [
                'sweet' => [
                    'red' => [
                        'watermelon' =>['id' => 1],
                        'cherry' =>['id' => 2],
                        'litchi' =>['id' => 3]
                    ],
                    'white' => [
                        'coco' =>['id' => 13],
                        'lucuma' =>['id' => 14],
                    ]

                ],
                'sour'  => [
                    'lemon' =>['id' => 4],
                    'orange' =>['id' => 5],
                    'tangerine' =>['id' => 6]
                ],
            ],
            'colors'   => [
                'black' =>['id' => 7],
                'green' =>['id' => 8],
                'blue' => ['id' => 9]
            ],
            'names'   => [
                'jack' =>['id' => 10],
                'paul' =>['id' => 11],
                'peter' =>['id' => 12]
            ]
        ];
```

I have a second array, with the elements that I want to search:

```
$results = ['coco', 'green','peter'];
```

I need to write a function that gives an output array with the elements and the tree of categories where they belong. Something like this:

```
$resultsInStructure = [
            'fruits'    => [
                'sweet' => [
                    'white' => [
                        'coco' => ['id' => 13]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'colors'   => [
                'green' =>['id' => 8]
            ],
            'names'   => [
                'peter' =>['id' => 12]
            ]
        ];
```

The function needs to be recursive, of course. Either walking the first of the second array, it's just that I can't manage to get it right... any help is appreciated !

Comment: "last level" is always an array with **only** `id` key?

Comment: the element has an ID key, but maybe other stuff. Perhaps price, stars, etc

Comment: If you pass ‘sour’ do you get the entire sour array back? Your example only contains keys which only contain an id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) to traverse the structure and references to put the value into the right place of the resulting array:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($structure),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

$filters = array_flip($results);

$keys = [];

$resultsInStructure = [];
foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === 'id') {
        continue;
    }

    // Put key to the stack, so we can get the path of results.
    $keys[$iterator->getDepth()] = $key;

    if (!isset($filters[$key])) {
        continue;
    }

    // Put the result in the right place in the tree structure.
    $tmp =& $resultsInStructure;
    foreach (array_slice($keys, 0, $iterator->getDepth()) as $_key) {
        if (!isset($tmp[$_key])) {
            $tmp[$_key] = [];
        }
        $tmp =& $tmp[$_key];     
    }
    $tmp[$key] = $value;
}
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e7d70cad9928629eaa97a2ce80c9c2e5b17059c).

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
function walk($arr,$results)
{
    if (is_array($arr))
    {
        $arrFound = [];
        $arrTmpReturn = [];
        foreach($arr AS $key => $val)
        {
            if (in_array($key, $results))
            {
                $arrFound = array_merge($arrFound,[$key => $val]);
            }
            $arrReturn = walk($val,$results);
            if (!is_null($arrReturn))
            {
                $arrTmpReturn = array_merge($arrTmpReturn,[$key => $arrReturn]);
            }
        }
        if (count($arrFound) > 0)   return $arrFound;
        if (count($arrTmpReturn) > 0) return $arrTmpReturn;
    }
}

print_r(walk($structure,$results));
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to my problem and a very clever way to solve it. Thank you @sintakonte